# multiple swipeable tabs in navigation drawer

Tags: android, tabs, navigation

i am trying to implement multiple siwpeable tabs per section from the navigation drawer however whenever i click on my section which contains tabs it fc's displaying the following error

```js
02-13 17:32:02.181    2275-2275/com.riara.university E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.riara.university, PID: 2275
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.riara.university/com.riara.university.SchoolsTab}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #81: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #81: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:377)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2144)
            at com.riara.university.SchoolsTab.onCreate(SchoolsTab.java:28)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: Activity must implement NavigationDrawerCallbacks.
            at com.riara.university.NavigationDrawerFragment.onAttach(NavigationDrawerFragment.java:212)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:903)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1206)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2159)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:297)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:377)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2144)
            at com.riara.university.SchoolsTab.onCreate(SchoolsTab.java:28)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

java main activity

```js
package com.riara.university;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.widget.Button;



public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
        implements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {






    /**
     * Fragment managing the beqhaviors, interactions and presentation of the navigation drawer.
     */
    private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;

    /**
     * Used to store the last screen title. For use in {@link #restoreActionBar()}.
     */
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
        mTitle = getTitle();

        // Set up the drawer.
        mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
                R.id.navigation_drawer,
                (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));








    }



    public void onSectionAttached(int number) {
        switch (number) {
            case 1:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section1);
                break;
            case 2:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section2);
                break;
            case 3:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section3);
                break;
            case 4:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section4);
                break;
            case 5:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section5);
                break;
        }
    }

    public void restoreActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
            // Only show items in the action bar relevant to this screen
            // if the drawer is not showing. Otherwise, let the drawer
            // decide what to show in the action bar.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            restoreActionBar();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_website) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.riarauniversity.ac.ke"));
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;

        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }



    @Override
    public MenuInflater getMenuInflater() {
        return super.getMenuInflater();
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }

        @Override
        public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
            super.onAttach(activity);
            ((MainActivity) activity).onSectionAttached(
                    getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        switch (position) {

            case 1:

                Intent intent = new Intent(this, SchoolsTab.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            case 2:
                 intent = new Intent(this, PlacesDetailActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            case 3:
                intent = new Intent(this, iCentreDetailActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            case 4 :
                intent = new Intent(this, AboutDetailActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;

        }
    }






}
```

xml activity_main

```js
<!-- A DrawerLayout is intended to be used as the top-level content view using match_parent for both width and height to consume the full space available. -->
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="MainActivity">

    <!-- As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
         space available using match_parent in both dimensions. -->
    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/container" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

               <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/bg"
            tools:context=".MainActivity"
            android:layout_gravity="center">



            <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                >
                <TableLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:stretchColumns="1"
                    >
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:weightSum="1">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="WELCOME TO RIARA"
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:typeface="serif"
                android:textColor="#472f91"
                android:textSize="40px"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="UNIVERSITY"
                android:id="@+id/textView0"
                android:typeface="serif"
                android:textColor="#472f91"
                android:textSize="38px"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />


                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="0dp"
                            android:text=" University."
                            android:id="@+id/textView2"
                            android:typeface="serif"
                            android:textColor="#472f91"
                            android:scrollbarSize="20dp"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:paddingStart="0dp"
                            android:paddingEnd="0dp"
                            android:textAlignment="center"
                            android:layout_marginTop="69dp"
                            android:layout_weight="2"
                            android:visibility="visible"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
                            android:layout_margin="0dp"
                            tools:ignore="NewApi,RtlCompat" />

                <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                </FrameLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
                </TableLayout>

            </ScrollView>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </FrameLayout>


    <fragment android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start" android:name="com.riara.university.NavigationDrawerFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/ViewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

please help as i have been stuck at this for several hours

Comment: Post navigation drawer xml code and java code using it.

Comment: @Aashish i have added the xml and java code